# JavaScript окошко

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Как реализовано окошко, которое появляется поверх страницы когда кликаешь на 
"новое сообщение" у друга на страничке. Для меня остается загадкой, почему не создается новое окно.

Буду рад каким-то ссылкам или примерам, этого метода.

Comment: извините, отряд экстрасенсов в отпуске....

Comment: Я спрашиваю не конкретно про вк, а про то, как это выглядит посредством js,jquery

Comment: Ошибаетесь. Экстрасенсы тут :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jquery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) спасет мир.

Comment: прекрасно)

Comment: @knes лично у меня впечатление, что он вам по телефону еще что-то объяснил )я, например, тоже нифига в вопросе не пойму.

Answer (score 1):

Динамически добавляются элементы HTML в DOM.